# DESTRUIR CUADRO DE DIALOGO MODAL - PYTHON PYSIDE

Tags: python, dialog, pyside

Tengo un problema a la hora de destruir un cuadro de dialogo en estado "modal", cuando lo destruyo se cierra el dialogo pero la ventana principal se queda congelada.

Este es el código que abre el cuadro de dialogo al dar click en un botón

```
def agregarViga(self):

        # CARGANDO PAGINA DE LA VIGA EN EL CUADRO DE DIALOGO
        self.dialog.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.dialog.pgViga)

        # CAPTURANDO EVENTO CLICK EN LA CAJA DE BOTONES DEL DIALOGO
        self.dialog.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.boton_clicado)
        self.dialog.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.destruir)

        # MOSTRANDO CUADRO DE DIALOGO
        # /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        self.exec_()
        # /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        # FIN agregarViga
```

el cuadro de dialogo tiene un "buttonBox" y necesito que cuando se de click en cancelar, destruya el cuadro de dialog con "self.destroy()", para ello ejecuto la siguiente función:

```
def cerrarDialog(self):
        self.destroy()
```

Cuando se ejecuta la función el cuadro de dialogo se destruye, pero la ventana principal se queda congelada.

Comment: Si no tienes algún timer por allí te recomiendo el sys.exit(app.exec())

Comment: Toda la documentacion de este problema aqui https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/